Is there a webhook that listens to a BIM360 hub for new projects?
I would like to know if there is a webhook that listens to our BIM360 hub for any new projects that are created. I would like to have a DB of all our project names and ID's. When I run the GET projects api endpoint it takes some time to execute due to the sheer number of projects we have on the hub. Therefore, having a webhook would be nice so when a new project is created, we can store the project name and ID in a lightweight DB for fast queries. I've checked the list of supported webhooks, but wasn't able to find one for new project creation on BIM360.
I found this post, but it's looking for new folder creation in projects vs new project creation

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Creating a new BIM360 project is to use Account Admin API, but unfortunately, there is NO webhooks support for Account Admin API at this moment. But ..., we have logged a wishlist item for this, ACSAPI-1333, to let our engineering team evaluate the possibilities.
However, it would be great to understand your use cases. do you just need a webhook event to get triggered when a new project is created?

Thank you for your comment. We want to know when the project is fully created so that we can then run another routine to populate the project with folders and files.

Thank you Charlie for sharing your use case. I appended your use case to ACSAPI-1333.
